# Create Extension for UAP App with Extension SDK

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I try to create a Visual Studio Extension for my Custom TextBox Control i developed. I Followed the following Tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh768146.aspx#ExtensionSDKs

Here is the SDKManifest.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<FileList DisplayName="CundsS Controls UAP"
          ProductFamilyName="Cunds Controls UAP"
          MinVSVersion="12.0"
          TargetFramework=".NETCore, version=v4.5.1"
          SupportedArchitectures="x86;x64;ARM"
          DependsOn="SDKB, version=2.0"
          CopyRedistToSubDirectory="."
          AppliesTo="WindowsAppContainer + WindowsXAML">
    <File Reference="CsControlsLib.winmd"
          Implementation="CsControlsLib.dll">
        <ToolboxItems VSCategory="Toolbox.Default" />
    </File>
</FileList>
```

This is the Project Structure of the VSIX Extension
[image]

I get the Following Error while Building the Extension:
Missing Reference WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework

I don´t know why this should be needed, because i developed a Windows Universal App Control and not a WPF Control.

This is the Project Structure of the Control:

[image]